# java char '\249' "not a statement" and "unclosed character literal"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, char, ascii

I have the folowing code:

```
char c = '\249';
```

IDEA underscore **'\249'** with **"Too many characters in character literal"** message.
And when I tryed to run the code I got **"not a statement"** and **"unclosed character literal"** errors.

Why is this happening?

At the same time **'\250'** literal works fine.

For my understanding we can use **'\'** construction to set char by ASCII code, right?

Also I compared outputs of:

```
c1 = '\63'; //3
c2 = 63; // ?
```

They are different and '?' is correct. So what is **'\'** construction used for?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a '\u' in there somewhere?  Java character is Unicode.

Comment: @duffymo ``\`` without `u` is an *octal escape*. See answers.

Comment: Java uses the UTF-16 character encoding of the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set; not ASCII. So, \u escapes are more natural than other numeric escapes. But, you shouldn't need to escape except for clarity.`'¨'` is the same as `'\u00A8'`; `""` is the same as `"\uD83D\uDE00"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, in a string literal or character literal, you can specify a character with an *octal escape*, governed by the [JLS, Section 3.10.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6).

> OctalEscape:
>
> \ OctalDigit
>
> \ OctalDigit OctalDigit
>
> \ ZeroToThree OctalDigit OctalDigit

Octal digits are the digits 0 through 7.  The escape sequence `\249` is illegal because `9` is not an octal digit, but the escape sequence `\250` is legal because it fits the 3rd production above.

When you set a `char` to `\63` that is Unicode character number 51, which is `'3'`.  When you set a `char` to `63` that is Unicode character 63, which is `'?'`.

Answer (score 4):

`'` is used for quoting a `char` value.

A `\` in a char literal is used to define an [`OctalEscape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-OctalEscape), and must be followed by 1-3 octal digits (0-7).

So, with `'\249'`, the `9` is not an octal digit, which means `\24` is one (escaped) character and `9` is another character, and a char literal cannot have 2 characters, so it is invalid.

`'\250'` is a valid octal escape for character 250 (octal) / 168 (decimal) / A8 (hex), which is Unicode Character ['DIAERESIS' (U+00A8)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a8/index.htm), aka `¨`